# Rails: change column name and not value in where clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How could I change the column name in the argument of a where clause? Something like this is what I'm after:

```
def self.filter_by_time(datetime)
  where('? < ?', datetime, Time.now)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def self.filter_by_time(datetime)
  where("#{datetime} < ?", Time.now)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def self.filter_by_time(datetime)
  where("datetime < ?", Time.now)
end
```